# Google Analytics Export API - nextPagePath data

Tags: google-analytics

I am probably missing something obvious, but I do not understand when I query:

```
start.date = DATE_START, 
           end.date = DATE_END,
           dimensions = c("ga:pagePath","ga:previousPagePath"),
           metrics = c("ga:pageviews"),
           filters = mypageofinterest,
           table.id = "ga:mytable",
           max.results=RESULTS
```

my data return as expected, all of the previous pages including (entrance).  However, when I modify the code to be nextPagePath

```
start.date = DATE_START, 
           end.date = DATE_END,
           dimensions = c("ga:pagePath","ga:nextPagePath"),
           metrics = c("ga:pageviews"),
           filters = mypageofinterest,
           table.id = "ga:mytable",
           max.results=RESULTS
```

only one line of data are returned; the pagepath and nextpagepath are identical with itself.  I replicated this result using the Query Explorer.

What am I missing or doing wrong?  I was expecting to see a large number of "next" pages, including (exit).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

ga:pagePath and ga:nextPagePath are not meant to be used together. GA should really return an error here.

Use ga:previouspagepath instead.